# Button that generates a random number between 1 and 100 on textview

Tags: android

Thats An easy questions for those who been in the android coding scene for long enought ! I have done researches , Studies about this questions. Tried it , But always had errors when Ran the application.

The questions is , How could I make a button , Show a Random number between 1 and 100 on a textview ?

Comment: Yes it is easy. Show us what have you done so far and we will help you.

Comment: Not sure if you are a native english speaker, but your use of commas is a tiny bit off :P.

Comment: Im french ! Sorry ! I'm trying to implement the codes but get errors

Comment: Pourquoi les majuscules apres les virgules? :-) C'est comme le francais, l'anglais, non?

Answer (score 8):

```
final Random r = new Random();
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
    public void onClick(...){
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(r.nextInt(100)+1));
    }    
});
```

Comment: Where would I put this ? how to declare wich button does the generation and wich textview shows the output ?

Comment: @Yaann follow developer.android.com for that

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample code that might help.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView displayRandInt;
    private Button updateRandInt;

    private static final Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(/* Your Activity's XML layout id */);

        /* Setup your Activity */

        // Find the views (their ids should be specified in the XML layout file)
        displayRandInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayRandInt);
        updateRandInt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateRandInt);

        // Give the Button an onClickListener
        updateRandInt.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int randInt = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
                displayRandInt.setText(String.valueOf(randInt));
            }
        });
    }
}
```